# How to make the closures shorter？

Tags: swift, closures

How to make the closures shorter？ I want to know the simple programming of the closures.

```
let closures = { (fillBefore: Bool, fillAfter: Bool) -> String in

    if fillBefore && fillAfter {
        return kCAFillModeBoth
    } else if !fillBefore && fillAfter {
        return kCAFillModeBackwards
    } else if fillBefore && !fillAfter {
        return kCAFillModeForwards
    } else {
        return kCAFillModeRemoved
    }

}

anim?.fillMode = closures((item?.fillBefore)!, (item?.fillAfter)!)
```

How to make the closures shorter？

Comment: you already have the shortest possible code.

Comment: I'm a StackOverflow newcomer and my English is poor, I'll be better. thank you, everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your case, I think that at some point you have to evaluate both of booleans, so I would assume that there is no "shorter" code for handling it.

However, you might be looking for a "neater" approach, so I would suggest to evaluate them as *pair* of booleans (tuple), with a `switch` statement:

```
let closure = { (fillBefore: Bool, fillAfter: Bool) -> String in
    switch (fillBefore, fillAfter) {
    case (true, true):
        return kCAFillModeBoth
    case (false, true):
        return kCAFillModeBackwards
    case (true, false):
        return kCAFillModeForwards
    default: // on your case, it would be the same as (false, false)
        return kCAFillModeRemoved
    }
}

let myClosure = closure(false,false)
myClosure // removed
```

Comment: I want to know if there is an omission in the closure. Using tuples is indeed a feature of swift. I had been using oc, so I did not expect this, thank you